# Version object is comparing two versions incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, version, compareto

I am using the Version object in order to run a CompareTo against two version numbers and making X happen if the version is >= versionA.

My issue is that in the below code, the CompareTo is declaring that VersionB is greater than VersionA.

```
Version versionA = new Version("2.12");
Version versionB = new Version("2.121");

switch (versionB.CompareTo(versionA))
                {
                    case 0: // Equal To
                        _doThis = true;
                        break;
                    case 1: // Greater Than
                        _doThat = true;
                        break;
                    case 2: // Less Than
                        _doNothing = true;
                        break;
                }
```

This comparison hits case 2. I am using a regex to match a firmware version being passed to the method, as you see here:

^\S+\s(?(\d+.*)+)\s*.*$

I will accept something along the lines of "Version 2.12" and this regex will leave me with just "2.12", which then gets initialized into a Version object.

Anyone have any ideas on why .NET is telling me that Version 2.12 is a newer Version than 2.121?

---

EDIT:

I have altered my code to be as follows:

```
Version versionA = new Version("2.12");
Version versionB = new Version("2.121");

if (versionB.CompareTo(versionA) >= 0)
{
     _doThis = true;
}
```

And it works correctly. Now though, if I compare "2.11" to "2.121", it also returns 1. Shouldn't this comparison return a -1?

Comment: `the CompareTo is declaring that VersionB is greater than VersionA` -- maybe I'm missing something, but 121 > 12, so isn't this exactly as expected?

Comment: VersionB **is** greater than VersionA

Comment: Yes, the switch statement you have makes no sense for the possible result set.

Comment: I'm wondering how you've got into case 2 when it never returns 2, actually the return range is -1,0,1

Comment: Get rid of the switch  less than is negaitive, 0 is equal, positive is greater than. The greater teh magnitude of the result, teh more different they are.

Comment: @L.B It returns a signed integer, so it can return 2. You can use it for say compare to n values and pick the closest before or after.

Comment: When I originally implemented this, I pulled sample code form an outside source and read that it returned 0, 1 and 2. I know now that this is incorrect. Modifying my switch to -1, 0 and 1 appears to resolve my issue. Thank you all.

Comment: It turns out the issue here is due to the versioning numbers I am interacting with. My original case statement was incorrect, but after modifying this, I was still running into issues.

My two versions are 2.121 and 2.13. The .NET Version object is simply comparing the minor revision number as thirteen and one hundred twenty-one, meaning 2.13 < 2.121. 

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 5):

The Version class provides operator overloads for the comparison operators, why not use those? It really makes the intent of the code clearer.

Meaning you can simply write:

```
if(versionB >= versionA) {
  _doThis = true;
}
```

To me, that is much clearer than calling CompareTo and inspecting the sign of the return value.

Comment: Can you provide a little more info on this? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Let me give this a try. Appreciate it.

Comment: Ohh..means of   >=  Operator Overloaded...   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.op_greaterthanorequal?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 4):

Version.CompareTo(Version) returns a signed integer

```
negative means it's before
zero the same
positive after.
```

The greater the magnitude of the result the further apart the versions are.

Get rid of the switch, or condition the return of compareto first.

Comment: I was just about to comment on this. My switch statement is incorrect. Sometimes it takes stepping back from the code and getting some outside input to help you realize your mistakes. Thank you!

Comment: I added a new finding to my original post, can you please review this and let me know what you think the cause is? Thank you.

Comment: looks like you've sussed it from your comment